# Emgucv C# Image Stabilization

Tags: c#, image-processing, emgucv, image-stabilization

I have two successive images which I want to stabilize using EmguCv in C#.

I found much information on how to perform image stabilization, however I could not find any detailed explanation on how to use Emgu to stabilize two successive frames (Actual code expmples).

I understand that I have to do the following:

1. Calculate the good features on the first frame by using the GFTTDetector() and get the Good feature points of the first Image (GFP1).
2. Then I need to compute the Optical flow using the CvInvoke.CalcOpticalFlowPyrLK() to get the good feature points of the second image (GFP2).
3. With the GFP1 & GFP2 I can calculate the Homography matrix with the CvInvoke.cvFindHomography() function.
4. Finally I have to use the  CvInvoke.cvWarpPerspective() to stabilize the frame.

So based on the above I tried to perform Image stabilization.

I have the two successive frames :

```
Image<Gray, ushort> FirstImage = new Image<Gray, ushort>(Width, Height);
Image<Gray, ushort> SecondImage= new Image<Gray, ushort>(Width, Height);
```

The  I tried to calculate the good features:

```
Emgu.CV.Features2D.GFTTDetector _GFTTdetector = new Emgu.CV.Features2D.GFTTDetector(500,0.05);
var GFP1 = _GFTTdetector.Detect(FirstImage);
```

However when I call the .Detect I get an OpenCV exception and I cannot proceed:

> $exception    {"OpenCV: scn == 3 || scn == 4"}    Emgu.CV.Util.CvException

Does anybody knows why I get this exception?

In addition I would appreciate if someone could post a sample code of how to use the following functions because I am not sure about what input arguments I shall use:

- `CvInvoke.CalcOpticalFlowPyrLK()`
- `CvInvoke.cvFindHomography()`
- `CvInvoke.cvWarpPerspective()`

Lastly  `_GFTTdetector.Detect()` returns a `KeyPoint[]` type, however the `CvInvoke.CalcOpticalFlowPyrLK()` accepts only `PointF[]` arguments for the good points. How I can convert the `KeyPoint[]` to `PointF[]`?

Comment: KeyPoint has a member Point which is of type PointF

Comment: maybe try it with real openCV, its a nuget packet these days and that makes its install a breeze.